# Creating Universal Library in Xcode 6

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I want to use the libCorePlot-CocoaTouch.a in order to make a graph of data but I kept getting a Mac-o Linker error from Core Plot. Seemed that the error was because I do not have a Universal Library for all of the architectures. From what I have read, is that the Core Plot library needs to be combined with the iphone and simulator libraries. Please correct me as I am very new to Obj-C.

I have tried using the following scripts with target/aggregate but none of them [Link 1](http://www.raywenderlich.com/41377/creating-a-static-library-in-ios-tutorial)
[Link 2](http://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/hwiki?Creating+an+Universal+Library+for+iOS,) work with Xcode 6, the issues are the following:
`Lipo: can't open input file: /Users/Wilbe1/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/GeoData_Grapher-blnjuxtseitfkfdfkgjpgzskbtwx/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libGeoData Grapher.a (No such file or directory)`

`Cp: /Users/Wilbe1/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/GeoData_Grapher-blnjuxtseitfkfdfkgjpgzskbtwx/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/include: No such file or directory`

Do I need to make a static library first and then a Universal? Could someone please give me a step by step instruction how to resolve this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to build your library for all the different architectures, then merge them with lipo like this :

```
lipo -create “lib_arm64.a” “lib_x86_64.a” “lib_armv7.a” “lib_armv7s.a” -output “lib.a”
```

This is how I do it personaly.

Comment: How do I build a library for all of the architectures you indicated?

Comment: You open Xcode with your project, and then build it for simultator x86, simulator 64, device x86, device 64. You'll have 4 .a after this. Between each compilation, check your product folder and copy/rename tghe .a in another folder to prevent erase by the other generated.

Comment: I tried building it with the different simulators but due to the Mac linker errors coming from the Core Plot Lib it does not want to build, I can't find the .a files in the products folder would that be because it does not build? I will make a new project and then build all of the simulators maybe that works

Comment: Ok I created the different lib.a files and they saved under product folder as described. I tried to merge them but lipo is looking for a directory how do I tell it where to look?

Comment: To run the command as I wrote it, you have to be in the directory where lay the libraries.

Comment: Thanks @David, I made the libraries and ran lipo on them, the problem was that I had to copy all of the files to my home directory for lipo to pic them up. I then added the lib.a to my project and the millions of errors disappeared. After that I got a Xlinker error and frameworks suddenly lost their references, I added all of the frameworks and the other 2 external libraries needed for my project but the Xlinker error is still there:

Comment: I just built the project now and the Xlinker error disappeared but it says "clang: error: no such file or directory: 'Accelerate'". As soon as I fix this framework then another appears that I have to fix. At the end when all of them are referenced again including the 3 libraries then the Xlinker error comes up again.